# Concurrent programming language being Turing-equivalent and difference between Turing-complete and equivalent

Tags: computability, programming-languages, parallel-computing, concurrency, computation-models

In [Is concurrent language CCS or CSP turing-equivalent in language power?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/is-concurrent-language-ccs-or-csp-turing-equivalent-in-language-power), the answer says that CCS or CSP is Turing-complete. But that does not seem to answer whether CCS or CCP is Turing-equivalent.

According to my understanding, Turing-equivalence and Turing-completeness is a different thing, but I may have been confused.

Answer (score 1):

CCS, CSP, and the $\pi$ calculus are Turing-equivalent.  As the answer there says, you can simulate a Turing machine in CCS, CSP, or the $\pi$ calculus.  That means they are Turing-complete.  It is easy to see that you can write an interpreter for CCS, CSP, or the $\pi$ calculus in C or Python or any Turing-equivalent language, so given a Turing machine, you can simulate CCS, CSP, or the $\pi$ calculus.  Therefore, they are all Turing-equivalent.

I suggest doing a little more background reading and study, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness, and chapters in undergraduate complexity theory textbooks.  That will help you solidify your understanding of Turing completeness and Turing equivalence.  You'll probably also find it helpful to learn about the Church-Turing hypothesis.